# Codeigniter Re-populate form in JQuery Colorbox when serverside validation fails

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, popup

I am creating a basic CRUD. All works fine except form repopulation. Here is the detail what i am doing.

I am displaying a list of all employees. There are some links Add New. And Edit and Delete with each employee. Now on Add New or Edit i populate jquery Colorbox and load my form in it. Here is the link that hits my controller method.

```
<a 
    href="<?php echo site_url('employees/form/'.$employee['id']);?>" 
    id="popUpEditFormTrigger" 
    return="<?php echo site_url('employees/entries'); ?>"
>Add New</a>
```

As you can see here i am hitting a controller method to load a form. This works fine. In color box form.js here is some code.

```
var dataString = $('#updateForm').serialize();
var url = $('#updateForm').attr('url');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {                
        $.fn.colorbox.close();                
    }
}); 
return false;
```

it closes the color box when ajax is successsfull. return false prevents the list view to go further and then

```
return="<?php echo site_url('employees/entries'); ?>"
```

is run and refreshes the entries in table.

Controller

```
public function submit()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name',' Employee Name'.'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('salary',' Salary'.'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description',' Description'.'trim|required');

    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        $data['name']           =   $post['name'];
        $data['salary']         =   $post['salary'];
        $data['description']    =   $post['description'];

        $result =   $this->employeesModel->insertEmployee($data);
    }else{
        $this->load->view('employee_form');
    }
}
```

Problem :

The problem is that i want to repopulate form in colorbox so that i can display the user validation errors. But the colorbox is always closes whether insertion is performed or validation fails. I want if the validation fails populate the form again in colorbox and prevent hyper link attribute return to go to site_url('employees/entries'). How can i do that? I am sure JQuery can handle this but i don't know how. Suggestions required.

Comment: Is that Ajax important for you because i am using JS to call url and it's working awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the concept you are making here is what's causing the problem. you want to close the form if there are no validation errors. but using the success function does not mean that. `success function` tells whether the `ajax request` has been made correctly or not regardless to the output from `php`. so what you need to do is...

on php side:

```
if(ok){
$data['res'] = '1'; // which means that everything is ok
}
else{
$data['res'] = '0'; // which means that you had a problem with your validation.
}
// then pass the data in json format or any other format you need.
```

the above code is just a **sample** to clarify the idea.

then what's important.. on your jquery side:

```
success: function(data) {                
        if(data.res == '1')
        {
            $.fn.colorbox.close();  
         }
        else
        { // display the errors
        }  
    }
```

so this success function tells that the `ajax request` has been made successfully. so inside it you can check if the validation is ok or not.

Comment: Well @mamdouhalramadan that's exactly what i am thinking now so i a going to add another function in colorbox.js that will be called instead of .close which is closing and calling return. New function will close the colorbox and pop it again with errors. Thanks for your idea

Answer (score 0):

Hey i don't know Ajax but i am using colorbox with JS for my application. I am also using it for same purpose only.

Include you `colorbox.js` file in the view file from you are going to call this `Add New` link.

```
<a href="javascript:add_new('<?php echo $employee['id']  ?>')">Add new</a>
```

Once when user clicks this link this will call an JS function which you need to write in the end of the file.

```
function show_channels(employee_id) { 

$.colorbox({href:"<?php echo ROOT_FOLDER ?>/controller_name/show_channels/" + employee_id,iframe:true,width:'515px',height:'374px'});
}
```

Now the colorbox will loads with the url which i specified in the above javascript function.

Now you need to write a controller function for processing data.

```
public function submit()
{
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('name',' Employee Name'.'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('salary',' Salary'.'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('description',' Description'.'trim|required');

if($this->form_validation->run()){
    $data['name']           =   $post['name'];
    $data['salary']         =   $post['salary'];
    $data['description']    =   $post['description'];

    $result =   $this->employeesModel->insertEmployee($data);
}else{
    $this->load->view('employee_form');
}
}
```